# How can I implement prototypes and integrate the clocks in this primitive javascript game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I decided to build a game in an effort to build up my skills as a developer. Although my game works at a basic level, I am unsatisfied with the architecture of the game. Basically, the player controls a fixed div with health at the bottom of the screen. The goal is for the player to collect black divs, dodge damage divs, and grab health and power ups along the way.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yung_terminal/pen/mMVdYa)

All non player divs are the same size and generated the with the same function. The 'falling divs' are also assigned randomly being assigned a class with a bias.

```
function random(min,max){
return Math.round(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
}

function dropDiv(){
    var length = random(0, 54) * 22.5;
    var velocity = 5000;

    var size = 1.5;

    var dropDivType = ["stack","stack","stack","stack","health", 
                     "health", "power", "poison","poison","poison","poison","poison","poison","poison","poison","poison","poison"];

    var typePicker = dropDivType[Math.floor(Math.random() * dropDivType.length)];

    var thisBox = $("<div/>", {
        class: `falling-box ${typePicker}` ,
        style: `width:${size}%; height:0%;padding-bottom:${size}%; 
        left:${length}px; transition: transform ${velocity}ms linear;`
   });


    //insert box element
    $(".game-container").append(thisBox);


    //random start for animation
    setTimeout(function(){
        thisBox.addClass("move");
    }, 40 );

    //remove this object when animation is over
    thisBox.one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
          function(event) {
$(this).remove();
 });
 }
```

Since all non-player, 'falling' divs are being generated with the same function, and are all fundamentally the same, I am thinking of prototype chaining for their generation. This isn't something I have done before and I was wondering if someone would give me advice on how to implement this. I am also not sure if I should put collision cases inside the falling div object or the player object.

Another concern I had was with the fact that I had multiple clocks in my game; one for player movement and one for generating the divs. I would like to integrate these clocks.

I am so very sorry to post such a wall of text on this wonderful site, but to be quite frank, I feel very lost and alone in my endeavor to get this done. Since I am not using HTML5 Canvas, my resources on creating a game engine/environment are very slim. Perhaps I should have dumbed down my game...